# UserControls in a Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I’m trying to use a class library to store a bunch of my user controls so i can reference this into multiple applications, this is so i can use the same control multiple times.

is this possible and if so how do you do it?

1. `usercontrol1` put into a class library
2. create a new project
3. reference this class library
4. then drag in the `usercontrol1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click on the toolbox: and select "Choose Items..."
then add the .dll file located in the class libary bin folder

That should do it.

Cheers.

Comment: So would you reference the debug or release dll? This is not the correct way to get the usercontrol to show up. Reference the class library. Make sure the referencing project has the same or newer version of .NET framework and build the solution. It should show up automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your own question. Create a new project: Class Library, then create new user controls in this class.

To add your controls to a new project add a reference to the .dll you created (the class library) under project references.

To add your controls to the toolbox...

Tools -> Choose Items
Browse -> Select the previously create DLL
Now the control appears in the toolbox.

Comment: yeh but in my toolbox, the user controls where not coming up, its a simple thing of just right clicking on this and add items... thanks for your help

Comment: i voted you up, but the other guy was first so i gave him the mark